# Jquery infinite scrolling up plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, horizontal-scrolling, infinite-scroll

We are building a web application, with the ability to send messages to other users and we've chosen to implement it the Facebook way. Meaning, a div with a fixed height, scroll bar of the div is at the bottom when the page is loaded. And when the users scrolls up we get the older messages with ajax. (Check out the [facebook message app](https://www.facebook.com/messages/))

**So does anybody know a good and stable jQuery plugin for infinite scrolling up?** 
I have found plenty plugins for infinite scrolling down and lazy loading. But none for scrolling up.

Thanks!

*Edit: 16 April 2012*
Made my own [jquery plugin](https://github.com/prebenh/jQuery-ScrollUp) for this.

Comment: Does this mean you answered your own question? If so, post your edit as the answer and accept it for future visitors.

Comment: I am pretty sure that users with reputation < 100 have to wait 8 hours before they can answer their own question. It was 4 days ago you asked the question, but I think since you edited it, now you are again subject to wait 8 hours before you can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made my own jQuery plugin for this:

https://github.com/prebenh/jQuery-ScrollUp

Here is an example:

http://scrollup.comule.com/